# Processing log files with PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, logging

Im going through a log file using php and it looks either like this:

```
11/06/05 09:17:59 TORMS068 11/06/05 09:17:59.234 TORMS068\Admin ... EPTH{2} ITEMIX{8} TELL{`` sdcsit49 - FileSystem /oracle/REF/sapdata2 Critical - MSGREC:1727:100 ``} USE{TELL} ATTACHMENT... xact{`NO`}
```

Where I used Ellipses to show there were a lot of other stuff

OR like this

```
11/06/05 11:29:38 TORM ... H{3} ITEMIX{5} TELL{``marble: initiator SCSI ID now 7 } File={ /var/adm/messages } - MsgRec 5174:406``} USE{TELL} ATTACHMENT{} UserParms{}   AnswerWait{`10`} BaudRate{`1200`} C... eviceId{``} TellExact{`NO`}
```

So it is either followed  by a **USE{TELL}** or **File={.*}**
I want to extract what is in the {}'s for TELL{} for every line in the log file.. 
Please help me, I'm going crazy lol

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your responses but the problem is that inside the {}'s there could be ANY character including other {}s and the only pattern is that it is followed by a File= or Use{tell}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I couldn't get a reliable method to work, but what I ended up with was

```
if (preg_match("/(TELL{)(.*)} (USE{T)/iU ",$data,$matches)) 
    $rowMsg=substr($matches[0],5,-7);
$rowMsg=preg_replace("/[}\. ]{1}\$/",'',$rowMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/USE\{(?<insideTheBrackets>[^\}]+)\}/", $line, $pat)) {
    var_dump($pat['insideTheBrackets']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [regular expression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) documentation is pretty good at explaining this stuff...

```
<?php
$str = "11/06/05 11:29:38 TORM ... H{3} ITEMIX{5} TELL{``marble: initiator SCSI ID now 7 } File={ /var/adm/messages } - MsgRec 5174:406``} USE{TELL} ATTACHMENT{} UserParms{}   AnswerWait{`10`} BaudRate{`1200`} C... eviceId{``} TellExact{`NO`}";
$pat = '/TELL{(``.*``)}/';
preg_match($pat,$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```